# How do i build hallium-boot and ubuntu touch for samsung herolte?

Tags: samsung-mobile, ubuntu-touch

I have tried to port hallium according to the tutorial here:
-https://docs.halium.org/en/latest/porting/get-sources.html
i flashed the hallium-boot using heimdall
And flashed the ubuntu touch rootfs

however it returns a neverending bootscreen whenever i flash it

i already tried using hybris-boot instead and flashing it with heimdall
but that just restarts everytime

ubuntu boot logo just gets stuck in a bootloop

Edit: my model number is SM-G930F